# Drivers for VT6421A Controller Card

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sata, pci, pata

The hard disk controller on my motherboard went out, so I'm trying to install [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YMJ6ZE) VT6421A PCI controller card.

Unfortunately, I've looked at a couple of posts on SuperUser and other forums, but I cannot seem to find any working drivers. I am aware about the slipstreaming method, yet at this moment I do not have any blank CD-Rs or DVD-Rs.

Luckily for me this computer happens to have a floppy drive. I am trying to install Windows XP on a drive attached to the card, but after pressing F6 and inserting the floppy with drivers on it, I select the driver listed for my card, but get an error about `viaraid.sys`. Is there a place where I can find working drivers for my PCI SATA/IDE card?

Comment: Hi Noodly_Doodly, welcome to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). It's good that you have done some research on this- could you perhaps include what posts you have looked at here on SU? That may help people trying to answer narrow down what doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: [Click the "drivers or support package" link on this page](http://www.via.com.tw/en/support/drivers.jsp)

Comment: [Direct download link](https://d34vhvz8ul1ifj.cloudfront.net/Driver/V-RAID_v6.10a.zip)

Comment: @Moab When I'm copying the drivers onto the floppy disk, I am going into the `VRAIDDrv folder -> drvdisk -> x86 -> XP` and copying the files from there onto the floppy root. I then go 2 folders back into `drvdisk` and copy `txtsetup.oem` to the floppy root, but after putting the disk in the other computer, booting the XP cd, pressing F6, inserting the floppy, and selecting the driver option for XP, I get this error: `File \x86\XP\viamraid.sys caused an unexpected error (18) at line 2108 in d:\xpclient\base\boot\setup\oemdisk.c.`

Comment: try copying all files to the root of the floppy. Delete the folder.

Comment: @Moab Do you mean all the installation files from the root of the folder that I downloaded? The folder itself it far too large to fit on a floppy, should I copy all of the drvdisk folder to the floppy root?

Comment: Just copy VRAIDDrv\XP\X86\VIAMRAID.SYS
VRAIDDrv\XP\X86\VIAMRAID.INF
VRAIDDrv\XP\x86\VIAMRAID.CAT
to the floppy. I can be found in VIA V-RAID Software Package V6.10a\VRAIDDrv\XP\x86

Comment: Its a driver "package" for all OS's it supports, so you have to sort out what specific driver/OS you need. Read the "Readme.htm" using Word.